# Null Hypothesis on regression coefficients

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing

I am running the following regression

Y(t) = C + alpha * X1 + beta * X2 + ....

My null hypothesis is structured in such way that alpha + beta = 0. How to test if my null hypothesis holds? i.e. how to find the t-stat or p-value in this case. I am fairly new to stat and any help/pointers would save me a lot of time for my thesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is fairly straightforward to test such linear constraints on coefficients with a Wald-$F$ test.

For example, in R, you might use the `glht` function of the package `multcomp`:

```
lmod <- lm(Fertility ~ ., data = swiss)
summary( glht(lmod,"Agriculture+Catholic==0") )
```

Answer (score 1):

If alpha + beta = 0, then it means that beta = -alpha and your model becomes y = C + alpha * x1 - alpha * x2 which factors to y = C + alpha * (x1 - x2)

So one option is to fit the model with a single x variable that is the difference of x1 and x2, then do a full and reduced model test between that model and the full model that fits separate coefficients on x1 and x2.